# set the property value for eclipse preference page

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

There is a property **"show line number" in (windows->preferences->editor->text editor)** eclipse which i want to tick by java code. so how i fetch the key of that property and set the value in preference page.

Note: I need to set the "show line number" option by default true.

Comment: You can import/export preferences in eclipse. Would that not suit your situation? Do you have to set it externally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will be correct solution for requirement:

String lineNumbers =
AbstractDecoratedTextEditorPreferenceConstants.EDITOR_LINE_NUMBER_RULER;
EditorsUI.getPreferenceStore().setValue(lineNumbers, true);

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4Preferences/article.html) shows how to access preferences from code. Try to search the property "show line numbers" and try to edit it.